# What will be the rest api query to get field values from site content type using rest api?

Tags: content-type, column, sharepoint-rest-api, choice-field

How will I fetch choice field values from site content type directly>

This is what I have tried:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/contenttypes
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to fetch? site columns in content type?

Comment: correct site columns in content type .

Comment: Do you want to get the site columns for particular content type or all site columns in your SharePoint site?

Comment: I have two choice columns in a content type , so i have to fetch the values of these choice columns .

Comment: yes , particular content type and this content type is not used in any list or library

Comment: Choice column values?? or choices in choice columns?

Comment: Choices in choice columns

Comment: If you know the names of your site columns then you can get using `fields` endpoint on web.

Comment: I tried isn't working

Comment: Can you please post what you used to get fields? Also try using below url in my answer.

Comment: Yes , i am doing through the example shared by you.

Comment: ok. let me know if it is working for you or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the names of your site columns then you can get choices for choice column direct using `fields` endpoint on `web`.

```
/_api/web/fields?$select=Choices&$filter=Title eq 'ChoiceCol'
```

Comment: Thank You Ganesh, This Query worked for me as required

Comment: Welcome. keep using this platform for any SharePoint related queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know content type ID or title on which you you need find all Choice fields

Query first content type and its fields whose type is choice. Below is example of ContentType Tasks and using filter we are getting only Fields of type Choice

```
/sites/yoursc/_api/Web/ContentTypes(@v0)/Fields?&@v0='0x0108'&$select=ID,StaticName,Title, TypeAsString&$filter=TypeAsString eq 'Choice'
```

[image]

Now you can loop through above fields to target your specific field with ID. Below is URI for TaskStatus column

```
 /sites/mysc/_api/Web/AvailableFields(@v0)?&@v0=guid'c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76'
```

You will get output as below

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
    },
    "results": [
        "Not Started",
        "In Progress",
        "Completed",
        "Deferred",
        "Waiting on someone else"
    ]
}
```